# Units.NET add unit without recompiling

Tags: nuget, units-of-measurement

We have a need to convert between units of measure on the fly, and Units.NET seems like the ideal solution, however, it is lacking some of the units we need (gallons per minute).  I know it is trivial to add to the specification file and recreate the classes, but it would be preferable to be able to simply use the nuget package. Does anyone know of a way to add units to Units.NET without recompiling the Units.NET solution?

It should be noted that we aren't married to Units.NET, we just need to be able to convert between arbitrary units of flow and length.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably get a better response asking this on Units.NET's github [issues page](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet/issues). There is a [wiki page](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet/wiki/Extending-with-Custom-Units) on adding custom units outside the main lib, but I admit this part is not very polished and could use improvement.

### Copied from the wiki:

If you are looking to add new quantities or units to the UnitsNet nuget, please see https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet/wiki/Adding-a-New-Unit.

#### Units.NET structure

Units.NET roughly consists of these parts:

- Quantities like Length and Force
- Unit enum values like LengthUnit.Meter and ForceUnit.Newton
- UnitAbbreviationsCache, UnitParser, QuantityParser and UnitConverter for parsing and converting quantities and units
- JSON files for defining units, conversion functions and abbreviations
- CodeGen.exe to generate C# code based on JSON files

#### Example: Custom quantity HowMuch with units HowMuchUnit

Map unit enum values to unit abbreviations

```
UnitAbbreviationsCache.Default.MapUnitToDefaultAbbreviation(HowMuchUnit.Some, "sm");
UnitAbbreviationsCache.Default.MapUnitToDefaultAbbreviation(HowMuchUnit.Lots, "lts");
UnitAbbreviationsCache.Default.MapUnitToDefaultAbbreviation(HowMuchUnit.Tons, "tns");
```

Lookup unit abbrevations from enum values

```
Console.WriteLine("GetDefaultAbbreviation(): " + string.Join(", ", 
    UnitAbbreviationsCache.Default.GetDefaultAbbreviation(HowMuchUnit.Some), // "sm"
    UnitAbbreviationsCache.Default.GetDefaultAbbreviation(HowMuchUnit.Lots), // "lts"
    UnitAbbreviationsCache.Default.GetDefaultAbbreviation(HowMuchUnit.Tons)  // "tns"
));
```

Parse unit abbreviations back to enum values

```
Console.WriteLine("Parse<HowMuchUnit>(): " + string.Join(", ",
    UnitParser.Default.Parse<HowMuchUnit>("sm"),  // Some
    UnitParser.Default.Parse<HowMuchUnit>("lts"), // Lots
    UnitParser.Default.Parse<HowMuchUnit>("tns")  // Tons
));
```

Convert between units of custom quantity

```
var unitConverter = UnitConverter.Default;
unitConverter.SetConversionFunction<HowMuch>(HowMuchUnit.Lots, HowMuchUnit.Some, x => new HowMuch(x.Value * 2, HowMuchUnit.Some));
unitConverter.SetConversionFunction<HowMuch>(HowMuchUnit.Tons, HowMuchUnit.Lots, x => new HowMuch(x.Value * 10, HowMuchUnit.Lots));
unitConverter.SetConversionFunction<HowMuch>(HowMuchUnit.Tons, HowMuchUnit.Some, x => new HowMuch(x.Value * 20, HowMuchUnit.Some));

var from = new HowMuch(10, HowMuchUnit.Tons);
IQuantity Convert(HowMuchUnit toUnit) => unitConverter.GetConversionFunction<HowMuch>(from.Unit, toUnit)(from);

Console.WriteLine($"Convert 10 tons to:");
Console.WriteLine(Convert(HowMuchUnit.Some)); // 200 sm
Console.WriteLine(Convert(HowMuchUnit.Lots)); // 100 lts
Console.WriteLine(Convert(HowMuchUnit.Tons)); // 10 tns
```

Sample quantity

```
public enum HowMuchUnit
{
    Some,
    Lots,
    Tons
}

public struct HowMuch : IQuantity
{
    public HowMuch(double value, HowMuchUnit unit)
    {
        Unit = unit;
        Value = value;
    }

    Enum IQuantity.Unit => Unit;
    public HowMuchUnit Unit { get; }

    public double Value { get; }

    #region IQuantity

    private static readonly HowMuch Zero = new HowMuch(0, HowMuchUnit.Some);

    public QuantityType Type => QuantityType.Undefined;
    public BaseDimensions Dimensions => BaseDimensions.Dimensionless;

    public QuantityInfo QuantityInfo => new QuantityInfo(Type,
        new UnitInfo[]
        {
                new UnitInfo<HowMuchUnit>(HowMuchUnit.Some, BaseUnits.Undefined),
                new UnitInfo<HowMuchUnit>(HowMuchUnit.Lots, BaseUnits.Undefined),
                new UnitInfo<HowMuchUnit>(HowMuchUnit.Tons, BaseUnits.Undefined),
        },
        HowMuchUnit.Some,
        Zero,
        BaseDimensions.Dimensionless);

    public double As(Enum unit) => Convert.ToDouble(unit);

    public double As(UnitSystem unitSystem) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IQuantity ToUnit(Enum unit)
    {
        if (unit is HowMuchUnit howMuchUnit) return new HowMuch(As(unit), howMuchUnit);
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be of type HowMuchUnit.", nameof(unit));
    }

    public IQuantity ToUnit(UnitSystem unitSystem) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override string ToString() => $"{Value} {UnitAbbreviationsCache.Default.GetDefaultAbbreviation(Unit)}";
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider) => $"HowMuch ({format}, {formatProvider})";
    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider) => $"HowMuch ({provider})";
    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider, int significantDigitsAfterRadix) => $"HowMuch ({provider}, {significantDigitsAfterRadix})";
    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args) => $"HowMuch ({provider}, {string.Join(", ", args)})";

    #endregion
}
```